# update state of list in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update state of `tickerList` variable, with the `data.ticker`
i tried doing like `setTicker(data.ticker)` but this doesn't change state of `tickerList` variable

how to do this?

```
  const [tickerList, setTickerList] = useState([]);


  fetch('/ticker').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
         
         
         setTickerList(data.ticker)     // here i  want to assign data.ticker to tickerList
         console.log(data.ticker)       // prints list of strings
         console.log(tickerList)        // prints empty list
    
  })


update 1

  useEffect(()=>{
    
    fetch('/ticker').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
         setTickerList(data.ticker)  
    })
    
    console.log(tickerList)
  },[tickerList])
```

by doing as above, `/ticker` endpoint is getting called infinitely
any way to avoid that?

**update 2**

```
 const handleClick =  () =>{
     fetch('/ticker').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
         setTickerList(data.ticker)  
    })

  }
```

Comment: Setting state in React is asynchronous, the state may not have changed by the time the `console.log` runs.

Comment: your code is working but the state is not update directly (async) if you return something from your function component you will see that state is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some performance purposes, setState actions are Async in react, that's mean the js engine will not wait for updating of state and next lines will be executed.
that's why you get an empty list!

[image]

in your case, after re-rendering, you can access to the new state value and use it in UI.

take a look at this example:

***round 1:***

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
setState((prev) => prev + 1); // 0 + 1 = 1
console.log("State Value", state); //result: 0
}, []);
```

***round 2:***

```
React.useEffect(() => {
setState((prev) => prev + 1); // 1 + 1 = 2
console.log("State Value", state); //result: 1
}, []);
```

EDIT (a problem in code): your useEffect will runs continuously because every time you change the `tickerList` and `tickerlist` is one of the `useEffect` dependencies.

Comment: yes, i got the error, i want to fetch only on a button click, what should the handleClick function look like? i have updated the question please see if i have written it in right way or not

Comment: @user4599 by using .then/.catch you don't need to use async/await!

Answer (score 1):

In react, state changes are implemented asynchronously, so if you log the state immediately after the change - you wouldn't see it.

Beside, you should make the fetch inside `useEffect` hook, or inside `componentDidMount`.

to see the state change you can do something like that:

```
useEffect(()=> console.log(tickerList) ,[tickerList])
```